# Restarting USB Touchscreen Device from the Touchscreen Driver

Tags: c++, c, windows, usb, hid

I have a Touchscreen Device which passes the X- and Y-Coordinates over Interrupts (USB) to my Touchscreen Driver.
When using more than one finger the Touchscreen Device gets stuck. In this scenario I want to restart the Touchscreen Device from the Driver.

Is this possible with the following function?
If yes, how do I have to fill the pbHidPacket?

```
pbHidPacket[0] = 0x05; // Report ID
pbHidPacket[1] = 0x00; // Interface No. Lower
pbHidPacket[2] = 0x00; // Interface No. Upper

dwErr = pHidFuncs->lpSetReport(
    hDevice,
    HidP_Feature,
    pbHidPacket,
    cbMaxHidPacket,
    INFINITE);
```

Comment: Needs more code, what's `pHidFuncs` ? Remember: there's a significant stack of drivers between your application and any USB device. You can't just send raw bytes from your app to an USB port on your computer, like you'd do with RS232.